# Hibernate column annotation for TEXT

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring MVC boot application with a MySQL database and I'm trying to get a TEXT field in my database. I have the following code:

Member.java

```
@Entity
public class Member {
private Long id;
private String name;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String biography;

private String country;
private String state;
private String city;
private Date dateOfBirth;
private String gender;

//Getters and setters
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wave
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

And here is the Hibernate it creates

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists member
Hibernate: create table member (id bigint not null auto_increment, biography varchar(255), city varchar(255), country varchar(255), date_of_birth date, gender varchar(255), name varchar(255), state varchar(255), primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

It still sets it as a varchar(255). Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `@Lob` from [javax.persistence](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html)... it's more elegant:

```java
@Column
@Lob
public String getDescription() {...
```

Answer (score 9):

In `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` class there is a line:

```
registerColumnType( Types.CLOB, 65535, "text" );
```

So based on that if you define your field like this:

```
@Column(length = 65535, columnDefinition = "text")
private String biography;
```

it should do the trick.

Comment: Sadly it still gives a varchar back.

Comment: try to add @Type(type="text") explicitly

Comment: It still gives me a varchar in the database.

Comment: As pointed [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-type-annotation) you should use `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "text" )` on String variable. Try it on variable but not on getter

Comment: Works like a charm. to take effect drop table first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as @Lob annotation, as @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")

```
@Lob
private String someField;
```

or

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String somefield;
```

Here is the Link to read more:
[JPA Annotation for the TEXT Type](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-annotation-postgresql-text-type#column-annotation)

Comment: Using @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT") worked.

Answer (score 1):

> **@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
> private String biography;**

Instead of the above you can use

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "biography")
private String biography;
```

**LOB:**
As the name suggests, a lob is a large object. In database terms, lob columns are used to store very long texts or binary files.

We can choose from two kinds of lobs:

1. CLOB – a character lob used to store texts.
2. BLOB – a binary lob that can be used to store binary data
   We can use the JPA @Lob annotation to map large fields to large database object types.

**Note**
When we use the @Lob record on a String type attribute, the JPA specification says that the persistence provider should use a large character type object to store the value of the attribute. Consequently, PostgreSQL can translate a character lob into a TEXT type.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the column definition could solve the problem (Only annotate with `@Column`, hibernate is clever to figure it out), but `varchar` is the replacement of `text` in newer versions of sql servers, so I think there is nothing wrong with using `varchar`. (255) is the default length.

Comment: Sadly only annotate with Column doesn't work either, it still gives a varchar. And I think it's weird if it's still a varchar. How would one get more then 255 characters in a database?